# "mysqld got signal 11" error

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, mysql-5.6, corruption

I have a MySQL 5.6.22 InnoDB database and just now, suddenly out of nowhere, when I try to start it up using /etc/init.d/mysqld start, I see this error in the error log and the server won't start up :

```
151204 19:08:17 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /u/mysql
2015-12-04 19:08:18 0 [Warning] options --log-slow-admin-statements, --log-queries-not-using-indexes and --log-slow-slave-statements have no effect if --slow-query-log is not set
2015-12-04 19:08:18 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-12-04 19:08:21 7f469c74d720 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 4231226488754
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-12-04 19:08:21 22922 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 4231231731200
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 4231235232564
2015-12-04 19:08:22 22922 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 03:08:22 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=209715200
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1024
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 612048 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x8dc805]
7 /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x494)[0x6660e4]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf790)[0x7f469c330790]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x999ecd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x99bad5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x984ace]
151204 19:08:22 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? It looks like there is an irreversible InnoDB corruption?

Thanks!

Comment: What were you doing that needed you to start mysql? Restore? data file movements?  BTW did you read this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105459/percona-mysqld-got-signal-11 ?

Comment: Hi, I had to start the MySQL server because I noticed it was not running for some reason. I did not see any errors before it went down. But when I started it again, it gave that error above in the mysql logs

Comment: It is imp to know how and why it went down. Was it normal shutdown or otherwise? What does error log say? Anything in dmesg? Readonly fs,  binlog issues, wrong ibdata file movements, data corruption and others can make you see this error. Easy escape is complete restore but I'd rather debug to the reason  behind this.

Comment: May be u can post more logs